# can't find variable __fbbatchedbridge (<unknown file>: 1)

Tags: react-native

I am working on React Native Android and While opening the app getting below error

```
ERROR: can't find variable __fbbatchedbridge (<unknown file>: 1)
```

My server is running and In developer settings IP & PORT are also correct

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This could be because your `init` command did not run properly. Try running `npm cache clean` and then `react-native init ProjectName`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Mihir: Still it is showing the same error.... and when I tap on "Reload JS" button it is showing following error
ERROR: "Could not connect to development server" 

1. Server is running
2. IP and PORT are correct in dev settings

Comment: I had the same issue. Try running ```watchman watch-del-all```, and ```react-native run-android``` again

Comment: @mbdev: `watchman watch-del-all` worked once and again started getting the same error... so I started logging by running the command given on React Native documentation `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` and started working all the time... And the interesting thing how logging command made it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes in development env. This happens when it can't load the JS bundle. There can be n number of reasons for not loading JS bundles.

1. React server is not running so try "react-native start"
2. Check if server ip and port is correct on the Device
3. Restart your modem sometimes it helps

Answer (score 1):

For windows, You should run react-native start after react-native run-android command.

Comment: I have done that also... as this command starts the server. But still no luck :(