# React Native Android apps suddenly stopped working. __fbBatchedBridge(<unknown file>:1

Tags: java, android, react-native

This is all brand new. Two weeks ago all my React Native projects were working fine. I walked away for a week or two, and then yesterday when I went to test them, I was getting this error.

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge(<unknown file>:1)`

There are a few below that,`runJSBundle` `CatalystInstanceImpl.java:160` etc, but nothing that's telling me anything useful as to where the problem is.

This is happening on all my projects, both in the emulator and on my phone.

I've spent two days on this now, and have read all the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300844/cant-find-variable-fbbatchedbridge-unknown-file-1) I can find from the past couple months but none have an answer. My best guess is that some dependency got upgraded and that made things all wonky. But I haven't upgraded anything in the packages, so I don't know.

I'm open to any suggestions.

[image: the error message]

The package launcher looks like this:

```
[9:34:58 AM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[9:34:58 AM] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[9:34:59 AM] <END>   Crawling File System (1208ms)
[9:34:59 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[9:35:00 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (357ms)
[9:35:00 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[9:35:00 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (286ms)
[9:35:00 AM] <START> Building Haste Map
[9:35:00 AM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[9:35:01 AM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (160ms)
[9:35:01 AM] <END>   Building Haste Map (535ms)
[9:35:01 AM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (2392ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when it can't load the JS bundle.

Do you see the bundle being requested in the log of the packager server?

Comment: I've edited to include the package launcher. It doesn't look like it's loading. Is there a straightforward fix?

Comment: Open the browser on your device and try requesting the JS bundle manually: http://%your_packager_ip%:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=android&dev=true if it doesn't load anything, try it from the computer running the packager, check if you have a firewall running preventing access to the packager server.